# Globally specifying username for all Mercurial repositories?

Tags: mercurial

Is there any way of having mercurial automatically create `hgrc`, so that I don't have to create it every time I create a repository?
I'd like hgrc to at least contain the following:

```
[ui]
username = geo
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the username in `mercurial.ini` or `.hgrc` in your Home directory and it will automatically be used for all repositories where it's not overridden by a local `hgrc`.

In TortoiseHg, this can be set using right-click and choosing `TortoiseHg/Global Settings...`.

See [the docs](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-the-basics.html#sec:tour-basic:username).